# How to go to url in same server without setting complete url address - JavaScript (with/without) jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know how to go to link / url / address, like;

```
window.location = "www.example.com/index.html";
```

or

```
document.location.href="www.example.com/index.html";
```

But suppose I want to navigate from `index1.html` to `index2.html`, how can i achieve this without providing the `www.example.com/` prefix? Please don't suggest that I set `www.example.com/` in a global variable / constant. The address may change to `www.example2.com/subfolder1/subfolder2/` to `www.examplea.com/`.... The mentioned methods works only in the case of **root** pages. I mean, providing `document.location.href="index.html";` will navigate the browser to `rootdomain/index.html`, even if I am staying in `rootdomain/section1/section2/somepage.html`. But I want to navigate to `rootdomain/section1/section2/index.html`

How can I achieve this by providing just the page name?

Comment: @Xymostech I am using this with jQuery

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `/` at the beginning of your string, it'll go to the local page:

```
window.location = "/index.html"
```

Comment: does not work in the case of sub folders. I mean in the case of `www.example2.com/subfolder1/subfolder2/`

Comment: @blasteralfred Are you doing `window.location = "/subfolder1/subfolder2/"`?

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.pathname = 'index2.html';`

You can also just use relative urls on the `document.location.href`.

What might be even better is `window.location.assign('index2.html');`. This is especially useful when you're at www.example.com/foo/.../index1.html and don't want to specify the whole path to get to www.example.com/foo/.../index2.html.

For more options, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location .

Answer (score 0):

Just like you would do otherwise, but using the relative path:

```
document.location.href = '/index2.html'; //relative path
```